# How to send attachment without moving to the server using PHP Mailer

Tags: javascript, php, html, phpmailer

This is my php mailer code i'm using.Here i want to send attachment without moving to the server.How can i send attachment with this.

```
 $mail = new PHPMailer();
 $mail->IsSMTP();            // set mailer to use SMTP
 $mail->Host = "localhost";  // specify main and backup server
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
 $mail->Username = "Mail-id";  // SMTP username
 $mail->Password = "password"; // SMTP password
 $mail->FromName = $name;
 $mail->AddAddress("Mail-id");  
 $mail->WordWrap = 50;           // set word wrap to 50 characters
 $mail->IsHTML(true);            // set email format to HTML
 $mail->Subject = $subject;
 $mail->Body    = " Name : ".$name. "\n E-Mail : ".$email."\n Message : ".$message. "\n";
```

Comment: Use the send upload example provided with PHPMailer.

Answer (score 0):

plz see this
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

```
$file = $_FILE['myfile']; //ur file
```

You can add attachment using

```
$mail->addAttachment($file);         // Add attachments
```

Comment: i  tried this one.But it returns error Could not access file:

Comment: This code is unsafe. Uploads should be handled as the PHP docs describe.

Comment: So can you suggest me safe code for sending mail @Synchro

Comment: Do what I said - read the PHP docs, use the send upload example provided with PHPMailer.